# Unable to resolve symbol when running code using Leiningen

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm using Leiningen (for the first time) to manage an app my writing. So far I've defined the project dependencies, installed the deps in the project lib directory, and I've defined a function. When I run `lein repl` from the project root and then call the function I've defined, I get the error `unable to resolve symbol`. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how to correctly run my app via Leiningen? Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

from the leiningen repl you will have to switch to the namespace your function was defined in with the `in-ns` macro.

```
(in-ns 'myproject.core)
```

then the function should be available
you could also `use` that namespace from the repl to include it in the default (user) namespace.

```
(use 'myproject.core)
```

after that you may want to consider looking into the `lein run`, `lein uberjar`, and `lein jar` leiningen tasks.

Comment: I wasn't aware of `lein run`, can you point me to where I can find mroe information? I've set `:main` to my project namespace, but I'm having a bit of difficulty using `lein run` with arguments; I'm continually getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)`

Comment: If you execute `lein help` (or even just `lein` on its own) a list of commands is displayed. You can dig deeper with the name of the command; for example: `lein help run`

Answer (score 16):

In my projects, for a core.clj file which contains a namespace defined thus:

```
(ns my-project.core)
```

... I set the `:main` key in Leiningen's `defproject` map in project.clj:

```
(defproject my-project "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "My project description"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.1"]]
  :main my-project.core)
```

So when I run `lein repl`, my core namespace is automatically loaded, and I see this:

```
mac:my-project scott$ lein repl
REPL started; server listening on localhost:31515.
my-project.core=>
```

Comment: If I were to use `:main`, does hot-code depolyment take place automatically?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are asking if the Leiningen automatically looks for file changes and loads them into your live REPL, but it doesn't do that. However, rather than restart the REPL you can execute the following to load the latest code: `(use :reload-all 'my-project.core)`